# ruby rescue block

Tags: ruby, eval, rescue, redo

I'm running a script with an API that often times out. I'm using `begin/rescue` blocks to get it to `redo` when this happens, but want to log what is happening to the command line before I run the `redo` command.

```
begin
#...api query...
rescue ErrorClass
  puts("retrying #{id}") && redo
end
```

Unfortunately the above script doesn't work. Only the first command is run.

I would like to force the rescue block to run multiple lines of code like so:

```
begin
 # api query
rescue ErrorClass do ###or:# rescue ErrorClass do |e|
  puts "retrying #{id}"
  redo
 end
```

but those don't work either.

I've had luck creating a separate method to run like so:

```
def example
  id = 34314
  begin
    5/0
  rescue ZeroDivisionError
    eval(handle_zerodiv_error(id))
  end
end

def handle_zerodiv_error(id)
  puts "retrying #{id}"
  "redo"
end
```

...that actually works. But it requires too many lines of code in my opinion and it uses eval which is not kosher by any means according to my mentor(s).

Comment: What is the purpose of `redo` in your code, I am not getting what you are looking for

Comment: Most of the time I'm able to start the process over again at that given id that the error occurred at and it works. Thus, I'm trying to do this without having the script break. There will inevitably be some cases where its the API command itself that is causing the error so I want to know when the script is getting stuck on the same id.

Comment: *I would like to force the rescue block to run multiple lines of code* - what is the problem? Do you mean last line not executing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are unnecessarily complicating things by using `&&` or `do`. The `&&` version does not work because `puts` returns `nil`, so by shortcut evaluation of `&&`, the part to follow is not evaluated. If you use `||` or `;` instead, then it will work:

```
begin
  ...
rescue ErrorClass
  puts("retrying #{id}") || redo
end

begin
  ...
rescue ErrorClass
  puts("retrying #{id}"); redo
end
```

but even this is not necessary. You somehow seem to believe that you need a block within `rescue` to write multiple lines, but that does not make sense because you are not using a block with single line. There is no Ruby construction that requires a block only when you have multiple lines. So, just put them in multiple lines:

```
begin
  ...
rescue ErrorClass
  puts("retrying #{id}")
  redo
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `retry` built in. This example is from "The Ruby Programming Language" pg 162.

```
require  "open-uri"

tries = 0
begin
  tries +=1
  open("http://www.example.com/"){|f| puts f.readlines}
rescue OpenURI::HTTPError => e
  puts e.message
  if (tries < 4)
    sleep (2**tries)  # wait for 2, 4 or 8 seconds
    retry             # and try again
  end
end
```

Comment: I think `retry` tries the entire `Enumerable` group (`array`)over again, `redo` only retries the given `Enumberable` member (`array[n]`) again